# Ignoring TF-IDF in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I have a use case of resume screening candidates based on job description keywords. Since I cannot afford change in score each time a new candidate profile is added to the content list (I assume IDF will change), I want to omit TF_IDF.

The indexed document is

```
{
                "_index": "crawler_profiles",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "81ebeb3ff52d90a488b7bce752a4a0cf",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "content": "Peachtree MBA"
                    }
}
```

As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ignoring-tfidf.html) here, I created following query

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "constant_score": {
          "query": { "match": { "content": "corporate strategy" }}
        }},
        { "constant_score": {
          "query": { "match": { "content": "strategy consulting" }}
        }},
        { "constant_score": {
          "query": { "match": { "content": "international strategy" }}
        }},
        { "constant_score": {
          "query": { "match": { "content": "MBA" }}
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting following error

```
[constant_score] query does not support [query]
```

All I want is to score 1 for 1-or-n existence of a term and 0 if does not exist(eventually skip tf-idf). Any help is appreciated.

ES version: 6.4.2

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: Apologies. Should have mentioned that. Its 6.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation that you have linked is for ES version 2.x. In 6.4.x there are some changes as shown here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

You should be able to update your query to something like this:

***EDIT:*** Updated the `"term"` filters to use `"match"`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "constant_score": {
          "filter": { "match": { "description": "corporate strategy" }}
        }},
        { "constant_score": {
          "filter": { "match": { "description": "strategy consulting" }}
        }},
        { "constant_score": {
          "filter": { "match": { "description": "international strategy" }}
        }},
        { "constant_score": {
          "filter": { "match": { "description": "MBA" }}
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this too. As per 6.4.x documentation _Filter clauses are executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching._. Does filter contribute to scoring? It strengthens my doubt, because I tried to search a term (verified existing) and yet, this query returns no hits.

Comment: Just no results. I have added the indexed document in original question for reference.

Comment: I edited my answer, try using the `"match"` in your `filter`.

Comment: Spot on. That worked (I have accepted it as answer). Thanks again.

Comment: I just observed, even though I give corporate strategy as a bi-gram, ES engine is giving score for individual term existence i.e corporate(score 1) and strategy(score 1). Is there a way I can force ES to search for collective phrase?

Comment: You can use a `match_phrase` instead of the `match` if you want the whole phrase to be found instead of the individual terms.